# R Potential Wildcard for changing numerical values

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, wildcard

I'm wondering if its possible to use a wildcard function in R to replace particular values in a dataframe?

So, if I had values of `c(10.32, 10.34, 10.35, 10.45, 10.56)` I would like a function that would replace all values with `XX.X5` to `XX.X4` (i.e. `10.45 -> 10.44` or `10.35 -> 10.34`).

Is there a replacement function that would work for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub`:

```
dat <- as.numeric(gsub("5$", "4", dat))

# [1] 10.32 10.34 10.34 10.44 10.56
```

***Update:***

This is another solution without converting the data to characters:

```
dat[round(dat %% 0.1,2) == 0.05] <- dat[round(dat %% 0.1,2) == 0.05] - 0.01
```

***Data:***

```
dat <- c(10.32, 10.34, 10.35, 10.45, 10.56)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea,

```
n <- nchar(x/5) == 4
x[n] <- x[n] - 0.01
x
#[1] 10.34 10.44 10.56
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by wildcard. If all you want is to scale a column from a data frame (ie, subtract a constant from it), then yes that is very easy given R's vectorized nature.

```
df$x <- df$x - .01
```

The mutate function from dplyr would also work.
If you only want to scale some of the rows, then the ifelse function is also very easy to use:

```
df$x <- ifelse(df$x<11 && df$x>10, df$x-.01, df$x)
```